# Create TensorFlow Dataset using File Links

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, hyperlink, numpy-ndarray, tensorflow-datasets

I have around 2.1 million multi-channel images stored individually as npy-file in a directory. The directory currently works as centralized storage for all images. The images with 25 Pixels x 25 Pixels x 10 Channels belong to a time series (multiple pictures for one day, >10-year horizon):

> main_directory/
>  ...2010_01_01_NY.npy
>  ...2010_01_01_SF.npy
>  ...2010_01_01_LA.npy
>  ...2010_01_01_BER.npy
>  ...2010_01_02_NY.npy
>  ...2010_01_02_SF.npy
>  ...

Ideally, I would like to use a sliding window and move forward year by year. To avoid storing a lot of duplicate data (the files are already 60+GB), I try to create a new directory with links to the files to create a TensorFlow Dataset using the Directory Structure (e.g. image_dataset_from_directory).

> main_directory/
>  ...Class1/
>  ......2010_01_01_NY.npy(Link)
>  ......2010_01_02_NY.npy(Link)
> ......2010_01_01_SF.npy(Link)
>  ...Class2/
> ......2010_01_01_BER.npy(Link)
>   ......2010_01_02_SF.npy(Link)
>  ......2010_01_01_LA.npy(Link)
>  ...

I tried using image_dataset_from_directory but that did not accept the npy-files or links. Does anyone know how to implement that, or is there a more efficient way?